# Advice with data model planning in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I'm pretty new at Rails and am setting up a new application that is user based. My data model is a bit complicated so I'm trying to figure out how much I have to associate with each user. Here's a generic rundown: a user has an inventory of items. Each item has the following:

Title
Date
Quantity
Price
Status [for sale, sold, not for sale]
Location

-BUT-

It is possible that if the user has many copies/versions of an item so that each location may have N number, with a price, some number are sold, unsold, etc.

I've thought about having a model setup like this:

```
User
has_many :items
has_many :locations
has_many :itemSets # <--- DO I NEED THIS???

Item
belongs_to :user
has_many :item_sets
Title
Date
Quantity

ItemSet
belongs_to :item
has_one :location
belongs_to :user # <--- ???
Quantity
Price
Status [sold, for sale, not for sale]
```

Is this the right association concept? And do I have to associate ItemSets to users? I'll never be showing them outside of their association with an item... Thanks and I hope this makes sense!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# users table shouldn't require any foreign key columns
class User
  has_many :items
  has_many :item_sets, :through => :items
  has_many :locations, :through => :items
end

# items table should have 'user_id' column
# other attributes would be 'title', 'date'
# quantity should be retrieved through the item_sets - see quantity method
class Item
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :item_sets
  has_many :locations, :through => :item_sets

  def quantity
    item_sets.sum(:quantity)
  end
end

# item_sets table should have 'item_id', 'location_id' columns
# other attributes would be 'quantity', 'price', 'status'
class ItemSet
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :location

  # now to make the user available you can either do this:
  delegate :user, :to => :item
  # or this:
  has_one :user, :through => :item
end

# locations table should not require any foreign key columns
class Location
  has_many :item_sets
end
```

Comment: A user's location should be available at the item creation time so that I would like to be able to grab the previously used locations for a particular user. Would I still be able to do that in the new item form? Right now I have form.association :location to accomplish that at the Item level. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @juliep - since Locations are being set at the ItemSet level, you should be pulling those from ItemSet.  Item can retrieve these Locations through ItemSet, and User can retrieve them through Item (which retrieves them through ItemSet).  So, yes, you can retrieve the previously used locations at the User level - ActiveRecord will simply join through two tables to find them.

Comment: excellent. makes sense. So long as this doesn't add unreasonable complication or performance issues, it sounds right to me. I'm going to try to implement this now. Thanks again!